# Surround code with babel plugin

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to surround my javascript code using a custom babel plugin.

```
    const wrapProgram = template('function wrap (){
  BODY
};
)
```

I'm using this template without success: it seems the order matters because I need the plugin to be executed at the end after all other plugins succeed.

Is there a way to define an ordering or maybe a template is the wrong way to keep sourcemaps ?

Thank you in advance for your help.